# GWT 2.5.0 war creation generates out of memory in Eclipse

Tags: java, gwt, war

We are developping a GWT 2.4 application using Maven. Due to the problem described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6809) we tried to switch to GWT 2.5. We also switched to version 2.5 for maven-gwt-plugin from org.codehaus.mojo. We had no problems with this arrangement (I mean running and debugging the GWT 2.5 application - using goals gwt:run and gwt:debug) until we decided to build a new war. For this we are using maven-war-plugin version 2.3. To our surprise the war file building runs out of memory no matter how much memory we allow in the vm arguments - we increased those until the limit of the physical memory (about 4 GB) but to no result. The combination of goals we use to build our war is "compile gwt:compile war:war", the sources are compiled correctly, but then the building process does not create even the first permutation as it runs out of memory.
 If we go back to version 2.4 both for gwt and maven-gwt-plugin the war is built correctly with no other changes. Has anyone been faced with this problem before? Any suggestions for a proper solution that would allow us to build a 2.5 gwt war would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you change JVM memory configuration? `MAVEN_OPTS`? `gwt-maven-plugin` forks a new process so make sure you use [`extraJvmArgs`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#extraJvmArgs) of the `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The last options we tried with are the following: <extraJvmArgs>-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -Xmx2048M -Xss2M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=D:\</extraJvmArgs>. Sadly, no heap dump is created when war building fails. Any other ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: Try running with `mvn -X` to make it display the exact command it uses to launch the GWT compiler (so you could try running it outside Maven); and also paste the exact error here .